# How do I pass a parameter file to a windows command script (.cmd)

Tags: windows, command-line, command, parameter-passing, mahout

I'm trying to pass parameters to the mahout logistic regression command through a file because the features are too much to fit in the command line, but the command line assumes that the file path is a parameter, how can I get it to read the file instead?

Comment: What OS are you using?  XP and later has a command line limit of close to 8 KB.  It may be possible to reduce paths in your command line if you can show us.  A parameter file also has a line length limit of close to 8 KB.

Comment: @foxidrive I'm using windows 7, I'm passing parameters to a mahout command and I need to pass around 20,000 words, and I can't reduce them.

Comment: It does help to explain the task in full, so that people with experience in your tool can offer some help.

Comment: From your edit I suspect that your `path\filename` contains spaces or `&`.  if so then wrap the entire `"c:\path\filename"` in double quotes.

Comment: I tried doing that this is the exact command I'm running: .\mahout "C:\Desktop\command" but it says " unknown program "C:\Desktop\command" chosen"

Comment: if that is exact - does the folder `c:\desktop` exist?

Comment: yes, I copy drag and drop the file into the command line so I'm sure it's correct

Comment: It would seem that `mahout` uses switches to determine what is on the command line. https://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/creating-vectors-from-text.html

Comment: Here is your answer I guess: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mahout-user/201409.mbox/%3CCAK5QfLNb8GebM0DQjpkbRkOBkvkw0ZFxLmavosJiT%2BZmZUSy_w%40mail.gmail.com%3E